# How to make WebRTC video streaming on local network working?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-streaming, sdp, rtcpeerconnection

I'm trying to establish peer connection between two clients via WebRTC and then stream the video from camera through the connection. The problem is, there's no video shown on the remote side, although I can clearly see the `remotePc.ontrack` event was fired. Also no error was thrown. I do NOT want to use the icecandidates mechanism (and it should NOT be needed), because the result application will only be used on a local network (the signaling server will only exchange the SDPs for the clients). Why is my example not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="local" autoplay playsinline></video>
    <video id="remote" autoplay playsinline></video>
    <script>
      const localVideoElem = document.getElementById("local");
      const remoteVideoElem = document.getElementById("remote");

      const localPc = new RTCPeerConnection();
      const remotePc = new RTCPeerConnection();
      remotePc.ontrack = (event) => {
        remoteVideoElem.srcObject = event.streams[0];
      };

      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          audio: false,
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          localVideoElem.srcObject = stream;
          stream
            .getTracks()
            .forEach((track) => localPc.addTrack(track, stream));
          return localPc.createOffer({
            offerToReceiveVideo: true,
            offerToReceiveAudio: false,
          });
        })
        .then((offer) => {
          localPc.setLocalDescription(offer);
          remotePc
            .setRemoteDescription(offer)
            .then(() => remotePc.createAnswer())
            .then((answer) => {
              remotePc.setLocalDescription(answer).then(() => {
                localPc.setRemoteDescription(answer).then(() => {
                  console.log(localPc);
                  console.log(remotePc);
                });
              });
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICE candidates *are* needed, as they tell you the local addresses where the clients will connect to each other.

You won't need STUN servers though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was pretty sure the local addresses are included in the SDP. Nevermind, my bad. After your answer, I searched for some information a bit more and found a good article, describing the process of "finding candidates": https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/. Nevertheless, I'm still a little bit disappointed the network information exchange is not included in the offer-answer exchange.

Comment: https://webrtchacks.com/trickle-ice/ explains the rationale for that.